# Is there a way to allow one user to register many participants for an event and to send separate invoices to each participant?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, invoice, payment, partial-payments

All of our client's members are either other associations or business "associate members." Many of the associations are managed by association management firms. The association managers need to track payment for each event registrant but they want the convenience of multiple registrations for the online registration. Similarly, Associate members may have satellite offices which need to receive individual invoice but they want one person in the organization to do all the registrations.

We just realized that partial payments from all the business/management entities apparently can't be applied to each registered user. So if  "Jo Bob" pays his fee, for example, they don't want that payment to be applied to "Mary Jane."

I don't see a clear path to resolve these competing needs. Does someone out there have a similar need or know of a solution to this user dilemma?

Answer (score 2):

I have my [Alt Invoice](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/com.megaphonetech.altinvoice) extension, which sends an additional invoice to someone based on their relationship.  I'd say that a developer could start from there to make an extension and be more than halfway there.